# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'strong_parameters'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, strong-parameters

I've installed strong_parameters gem without any problems and it was working. Although, my rails console stop working from nothing and now I can't run the console or server again. I have this message when I try to run both:

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in  require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'strong_parameters'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from c:/Sites/myrubyblog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I've uninstalled and installed it again. The error still happens though. Could anyone help me? I'm new on RoR. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the gem to your gemfile? Rails will auto-require gems that it finds in the gemfile.

Comment: Yes, I did.   gem 'strong_parameters'

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 4,you don't need to add it the gem file. It's already included. Just delete it from your gemfile and you will be good to go. :)